# DocuSign SOAP API for User list

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I am trying to get the users associated with DocuSign account using SOAP API.
I tried API GetMembershipSummary(), but is giving an error "Invalid_Login" although X-DocuSign-Authentication is set, and valid email id of admin is provided.

I did noticed that this method is reserved by DocuSign based on [this](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-soap-api/reference/Account-Management-Service-API/GetMembershipSummary) link

The rest API /users is working fine, but I still need equivalent SOAP API.

Answer (score 0):

you are correct. this is one of these things that can only be done using the REST API.
The SOAP API is not currently supported. Meaning, we won't add features or make modifications to it. I highly recommend to use the REST API. If you already have a SOAP Application, you can use the REST API for newer features.

Comment: Thanks Inbar... as per DocuSign support there is no such SOAP API which can help me with this requirement... so I am just validating if user is assigned to the said account or not....